# Word Search II java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search

I tried to implement the Trie and dfs with backtracking to solve the LeetCode problem Word Search II, but it keeps telling me my dfs method is out of bounds:

```
class Solution {
    class TrieNode{
        TrieNode[] children = new TrieNode[26];
        String word;
    }
    public TrieNode buildTrie(String[] words){
        TrieNode root =new TrieNode();
        for(String w:words){
            TrieNode current=root;
            for(char c: w.toCharArray()){
                int i = c-'a';
                if(current.children[i]==null)
                    current.children[i]=new TrieNode();
                current=current.children[i];
            }
            current.word=w;
        }
        return root;
    }
    public List<String> findWords(char[][] board, String[] words) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList();
        TrieNode root = buildTrie(words);
        
        for(int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; i<board[0].length; j++){
                dfs(board,i,j,root,result);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    private void dfs(char[][] board, int i, int j, TrieNode root, List<String> result){
        char c = board[i][j];
        if(c == '*'|| root.children[c-'a']==null)
            return;
        root= root.children[c-'a'];
        if(root.word != null){
            result.add(root.word);
            root.word = null; //de-duplication
        }
        board[i][j] = '*';
        if(i>0) dfs(board, i-1,j, root, result); //up
        if(j>0) dfs(board, i, j-1, root,result);//left
        if(i<board.length-1) dfs(board, i+1, j, root, result);//down
        if(j<board[0].length-1) dfs(board, i, j+1, root, result);//right
        board[i][j]=c; //backtrack
    }
}
```

and here is the error I kept receiving:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
  at line 32, Solution.dfs
  at line 26, Solution.findWords
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 87, __Driver__.main
```

The error happens at line char c = board[i][j].
I believe my double for loops are within the available range so it should be impossible that there is a OutOfBoundException happening at that specific line.

Answer (score 0):

mistyped i instead of j in findWord method.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain more ? This is quite short to be a good answer that can help other people with same issue

Comment: @Elikill58 In the second for loop statement in the findWord method, the constraint should be j<board[0].length instead of i<board[0].length.

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to add it in your post